# Cannot find the duplicate identifier that the compiler finds.

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

We have the following class definition:

```
export class RegistrationForm {  

}
```

The Visual Studio Code errors and warnings panel says:

```
[ts] Duplicate identifier 'RegistrationForm'. src/registration-form.ts(1,14)

[ts] Duplicate identifier 'RegistrationForm'. src/registration-form.ts(2,15)
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Duplicate identifier.]

We have done a Find in Files and found no other declarations of `RegistrationForm`.

Why is TypeScript complaining about a duplicate identifier that doesn't exist? How do we resolve this?

Comment: maybe the class gets included twice somehow?

Comment: change the RegistrationForm in that file to RegistrationFormOther (or any other name) and see if it still finds RegistrationForm? is that snippet the entire contents of registration-form.ts?

Comment: @JamesManning It doesn't find a duplicate identifier after renaming to `RegistrationFormXXX`.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin does it still compile, though?  If so, then it would appear the compiler is finding another place declaring that class.  Maybe you're accidentally including the output js (src/registration-form.js maybe?) as part of the compiler input?

Comment: @JamesManning Yes. The JS output is part of the compiler output. It goes into a *.js file. Does the TypeScript compiler consider that to be TypeScript?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Depends on what files you're passing to the compiler.  Are you using a tsconfig.json?  As a test you could move the src/registration-form.js to some other temp dir and then see if the compiler fails to find the RegistrationForm class, since that would seem to confirm it's getting it from that file instead of somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is TypeScript complaining about a duplicate identifier that doesn't exist? How do we resolve this?

Suspect its an issue in `tssserver`. You probably have two `tsconfig.json` files and this file is somehow (due to a failed path uniqueness check) getting included twice.

## More

To be sure its not a compiler error and just an IDE error you can run `tsc` on the command line or give another IDE a go (e.g. http://alm.tools/ )